# Popper.js Modifiers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, popper.js

In our React & Typescript app, we are using [react-datepicker lib](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker), which itself uses popper.js. I'm trying to assign `PopperModifiers`, just as shown here: https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-configure-popper-properties

But even if we use **exactly** what is in the example, we get the following typescript error:

```
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ReactDatePickerProps |
Readonly<ReactDatePickerProps>): ReactDatePicker', gave the following
error.
     Type '({ name: string; options: { offset: number[]; }; } | { name: string; options: { rootBoundary: string; tether: false; altAxis: true;
 }; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Modifiers'.
       Types of property 'shift' are incompatible.
         Type '() => { name: string; options: { offset: number[]; }; } | { name: string; options: { rootBoundary: string; tether: false;
 altAxis: true; }; } | undefined' has no properties in common with type
 'BaseModifier'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ReactDatePickerProps,
 context: any): ReactDatePicker', gave the following error.
     Type '({ name: string; options: { offset: number[]; }; } | { name: string; options: { rootBoundary: string; tether: false; altAxis: true;
 }; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Modifiers'.
       Types of property 'shift' are incompatible.
         Type '() => { name: string; options: { offset: number[]; }; } | { name: string; options: { rootBoundary: string; tether: false;
 altAxis: true; }; } | undefined' has no properties in common with type
 'BaseModifier'.ts(2769)
```

Why can't we assign the Modifiers array like it is in the example? Anyone has an example of how popper modifiers are used with typescript?

EDIT: What really confuses me is this property of the Popper.Modifiers type:

```html
[name: string]: (BaseModifier & Record<string, any>) | undefined;
```

Can someone please explain it here?

EDI2: This is our current implementation of the react-datepicker, problem is the popperModifier attribute:

```
 <DatePicker
                selected={this.value ? new Date(this.value) : null}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                peekNextMonth
                showMonthDropdown={this.props.showMonthDropdown}
                showYearDropdown={this.props.showYearDropdown}
                dropdownMode={this.props.dropdownMode}
                dateFormat={i18next.t("common.dateformat")}
                popperPlacement="bottom-end"
                popperClassName="da-datepicker-popup"
                popperModifiers={[
                    {
                      name: "offset",
                      options: {
                        offset: [5, 10],
                      },
                    },
                    {
                      name: "preventOverflow",
                      options: {
                        rootBoundary: "viewport",
                        tether: false,
                        altAxis: true,
                      },
                    },
                  ]}
                includeDates={this.props.availableDates}
                adjustDateOnChange={false}
                yearDropdownItemNumber={this.props.yearDropdownItemNumber}
                maxDate={this.props.maxDate}
                minDate={this.props.minDate}
                strictParsing
                portalId="root-portal" />
```

Comment: Could you prove your current code?

Comment: @Ryan Added code

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the type definitions.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-datepicker

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm currently very bussy but I'll definitely try this out. I also tried raising the issue on github page of popper.js, was only told it's an old bug: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/3180

Comment: Sadly this did not help, we still have to use '@ts-ignore' before .popperModifiers() for typescript to let us compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `react-popper` docs.

https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/modifiers/